# Where is the "Number" (Text Box Properties) toolbar when using the Visual Studio Reporting Services extension?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am using the SSRS Reporting Services extension in Visual Studio 2022.  I like it because it has an "output" window, and a project-level deployment option.

But today, I can't find the "Number" toolbar in VS, that I see in Report Builder.  In Report Builder, clicking on the down-right arrow brings up the *Text Box Properties* dialog.  I use the Number toolbar and the *Text Box Properties* dialog frequently, and I imagined that the authors of the Reporting Services extension would make it a high priority for implementation.

[image: Report Builder ribbon]

In the second image, I'm showing the VS2022 toolbar, with all three "Report" toolbars in the second row.  None of the buttons supports the "Number" functions, and none of the buttons brings up the "Text Box Properites" dialog.

[image: V2022 toolbar screenshot]

So the question is whether this toolbar has been overlooked by the extension authors, or if it's present but I don't know how to find/enable the "Number" toolbar.

The work-around is to right-click the text box and choose "Text Box Properties", but of course this takes a bit longer, and for a command that I use frequently, it makes a difference.

Incidentally, if anybody with enough reputation could add the tag "reporting-services-extension", I think it would be a useful for others as well.

Comment: I don't think this is available in Visual Studio. I've been building reports in SSRS for about  18 years and never had the need for it, I always have the properties panel open and do all the formatting there, once you get the hang of it it's faster in my opinion. For example, I often need to format all numeric textboxes to 2 decimal places with thousand separators so I select all the objects I want to format then type n2 in the format property and it's done.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - Interesting... I've tried to multi-select a number of times and it has never worked for me; I update collections of cells in Excel all the time.  Do you multi-select in a Reporting Services project or Report Builder?  Do you do anything "special" to multi-select (i.e. lasso versus Ctrl+click...) ?  And do you use the right-click properties or the f4 properties when you multi-select?  thx

Comment: I just use normal selection controls (dragging across multiple items or Ctrl+Click). There are limitations so you cannot always select across column groups for example. I only ever use Visual Studio, not report builder and I update multiple items using the properties pane (F4).